# performance grep vs perl -ne

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I made a performance test with really surprising result: perl is more than 20 times faster!

Is this normal? 
Does it result from my regular expression?
is egrep far slower than grep?
... i tested on a current cygwin and a current OpenSuSE 13.1 in virtualbox.

Fastest Test with perl:

```
time zcat log.gz \
| perl -ne 'print if ($_ =~ /^\S+\s+\S+\s+(ERROR|WARNING|SEVERE)\s/ )' 
| tail
2014-06-24 14:51:43,929 SEVERE ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-13             SessionDataUpdateManager                cannot register active data when window has no name
2014-06-24 14:52:01,031 ERROR  HFN SI ThreadPool(4)-442        CepEventUnmarshaler                     Unmarshaled Events Duration: 111
2014-06-24 14:52:03,556 ERROR  HFN SI ThreadPool(4)-444        CepEventUnmarshaler                     Unmarshaled Events Duration: 52
2014-06-24 14:52:06,789 SEVERE ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-1              SessionDataUpdateManager                cannot register active data when window has no name
2014-06-24 14:52:06,792 SEVERE ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-1              SessionDataUpdateManager                cannot register active data when window has no name
2014-06-24 14:52:07,371 SEVERE ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-9              SessionDataUpdateManager                cannot register active data when window has no name
2014-06-24 14:52:07,373 SEVERE ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-9              SessionDataUpdateManager                cannot register active data when window has no name
2014-06-24 14:52:07,780 SEVERE ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-11             SessionDataUpdateManager                cannot register active data when window has no name
2014-06-24 14:52:07,782 SEVERE ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-11             SessionDataUpdateManager                cannot register active data when window has no name
2014-06-24 15:06:24,119 ERROR  HFN SI ThreadPool(4)-443        CepEventUnmarshaler                     Unmarshaled Events Duration: 117

real    0m0.151s
user    0m0.062s
sys     0m0.139s
```

fine!

far slower test with egrep:

```
time zcat log.gz \
| egrep '^\S+\s+\S+\s+(ERROR|WARNING|SEVERE)\s' 
| tail
...

real    0m2.454s
user    0m2.448s
sys     0m0.092s
```

(Output was same as above...)

finally even slower grep with different notation (my first try)

```
time zcat log.gz \
| egrep '^[^\s]+\s+[^\s]+\s+(ERROR|WARNING|SEVERE)\s'
| tail
...

real    0m4.295s
user    0m4.272s
sys     0m0.138s
```

(Output was same as above...)

The ungzipped file size is about 2.000.000 lines an un-gzip-ped 500MBytes - matching line count is very small.

my tested versions:

- OpenSuSE with grep (GNU grep) 2.14
- cygwin with grep (GNU grep) 2.16

perhaps some Bug with newer grep versions?

Comment: grep appears to be faster during a test on my own machine: grep=`0m0.011s`, perl=`0m0.024s`. How large is your file?

Comment: interestingly, repeated runs of this show them at about the same time on average.

Comment: That's pretty hard to believe.  I would have assumed the overhead of Perl alone would have shifted the performance advantage to grep.  I do know the '|' is supposed to be among the least efficient Regex atoms.  Maybe that factors in?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make the Perl a little bit faster by making the parentheses non-capturing:

```
(?:ERROR|WARNING|SEVERE)
```

Also, it's unnecessary to match against `$_`.  `$_` is assumed if there is nothing specified.  That's why it exists.

```
perl -ne 'print if /^\S+\s+\S+\s+(?:ERROR|WARNING|SEVERE)\s/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You get tricked by your operating system's cache. When reading and grepping files some layers to the filesystem get walked through:

- Harddrive own cache
- OS read cache

To really know what's going on it's a good idea to warm up these caches by running some tests which do their work but do not count. After these test stop your runnning time.

Comment: surely not: the last (shown above) run occured in the given order: the fast perl run was first (so not yet cached...) And also that was, what triggerde me to analyze this more deeply: the egrep test has no visible iowait seeable in top or so... the perl test did show up to 30% iowait i guess.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Hamel commented.... not using the "|" atom grep becomes faster about 10+ times - still slower than perl.

```
time zcat log.gz \
| egrep '^[^\s]+\s+[^\s]+\s+(ERROR)\s'
| tail
...
real    0m0.216s
user    0m0.062s
sys     0m0.123s
```

So with 2 "|" atoms the grep run gets more than 3 times slower than running three greps after each other - sounds like a Bug for me... any earlier grep version to test around? i have a reHat5 also... grep seems similar slow there...